# How to change PrettyPrint's default indentation?

Tags: tabs, indentation, spaces

I'm using [PrettyPrint](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and its default indent is 4 spaces. I didn't found an answer on google code site. How to change it to 2 spaces?

**Update**

I have found the solution.

```
pre {
    tab-size: 4;
}
```